# Is it possible to determine the failed part of a Step Function from an EventBridge execution event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html
in this page,
I can see examples of Step Functions sending events to EventBridge.

especially, the followings are example of execution failed

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "315c1398-40ff-a850-213b-158f73e60175",
    "detail-type": "Step Functions Execution Status Change",
    "source": "aws.states",
    "account": "012345678912",
    "time": "2019-02-26T19:42:21Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
      "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:execution:state-machine-name:execution-name"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:execution:state-machine-name:execution-name",
        "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:012345678912:stateMachine:state-machine",
        "name": "execution-name",
        "status": "FAILED",
        "startDate": 1551225146847,
        "stopDate": 1551225151881,
        "input": "{}",
        "inputDetails": {
             "included": true
        },
        "output": null,
        "outputDetails": null
    }
}
```

From the event, Can I know which part of state function failed?
(for example, lambda in state function failed)

It seems impossible..